# How to order an Access query by a column of times

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a pretty basic query, but I'd like it to return the results in order from the earliest time to the latest. The column in question is a "short time." This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT *
FROM tasksetup
ORDER BY whenend ASC
```

What's the proper syntax to get this to work?

As an update:
When I run this query, it works just fine in that it completes. However, the completed query is not ordered the way I'd like. It returns the results in about the same order as they are in the table, rather than ordered by `whenend`.

Update 2: I guess it does work. I don't know what was different yesterday, but now its ordering just fine. Oh computer science.

Comment: Um... does that syntax **not** work? Because it looks correct to me. Please elaborate on what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why your query doesn't work ... unless whenend includes a date component which is not visible in your format. The Jet/ACE Date/Time data type **always** includes an integer component to represent the date; the fractional component represents the time of day.

See what you get with this:

```
SELECT Format(whenend, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss") AS full_date_time
FROM tasksetup
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Perhaps this session in the Immediate Window will help clarify Date/Time data type:

```
? Now()
11/5/2010 2:19:54 PM 
? Format(Now(), "short time")
14:20
? CDbl(Now())
 40487.5977546296 
? CDate(0)
12:00:00 AM 
? Format(CDate(0), "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
1899/12/30 00:00:00
```

**Update**: I created a table named tasksetup with a Date/Time field named whenend with the field's Format property set to Short Time.  And I added 2 rows.  Running your original query produces this result, which is *apparently* wrong:

```
whenend
2:00
1:00
```

However, the query I suggested runs without error, and reveals what is really going on:

```
full_date_time
1899/12/30 02:00:00
2010/11/06 01:00:00
```

You can use the TimeValue() function to ignore the date component of Date/Time values.  Perhaps this query would give you the results you originally wanted.

```
SELECT TimeValue(whenend) AS ignore_dates
FROM tasksetup
ORDER BY 1 ASC;

ignore_dates
1:00:00 AM
2:00:00 AM
```

Comment: i get a lovely "too few parameters. expected 1" error when I run that query. Its definitely a short time, not a date in the database. The data type is "Date/Time" but the format is "Short Time."

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to adjust the ORDER BY.  See revision above.

Comment: The point is that format only controls how the data is displayed, not what's stored.  A Date/Time field will **always** include a (whole number) date component.

Comment: That is, format controls the string representation for human beings. It has nothing at all to do with the data storage format.

Comment: so is whenend DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE, MINUTE TO SECOND, an INTERVAL?

Comment: @HansUP - I tried the revised query and got the same results. :(